# MySQL : Can't connect to table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect my website to the MySQL table.

Here is my code;

```
<?php
$v1 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ('.$nompage.') ORDER BY id');
if($v1 === FALSE) {
    die('Erreur lors de la selection de la table.'); // TODO: meilleur erreur
}
while($liste = mysql_fetch_array($v1)){
?>

<tr>
<th><?php if(isset($liste['nom'])){
  echo $liste["nom"];} ?></th>
<th><a href="<?php echo $liste['lien1']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
<?php echo $liste['lien1']; ?></a></th>
<th><?php echo $liste['autre']?></th>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

The `$nompage` fonction is ->

```
$nompage = htmlspecialchars($_GET["nom"]);
$nompage = mysql_real_escape_string($nompage);
```

I can see 4 row, because I have 4 items in my tables.

This is the error I get on the second and third column.

```
Notice: Undefined index: lien1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\show.php on line 102
Notice: Undefined index: autre in C:\xampp\htdocs\show.php on line 103
```

Comment: try mysql_query('SELECT * FROM $nompage ORDER BY id');

Comment: Do not add the table name between quotes. You can escape the name of the table with ` characters.

Comment: @RakeshSharma With those quotes? That won't work!

Comment: @RakeshSharma Error : `Erreur lors de la selection de la table.` Unable to select the table.

Comment: Are you not first connecting? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php - Plus, where is `$nompage` being first defined? You've got code that's marked as defined "below". Show us the **actual way** you're using it.

Comment: do you have columns called `lien1` and `autre` in the table set in `$nompage` in your database?

Comment: @lolka_bolka `mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '$nompage' ORDER BY id');
if($v1 === FALSE) {` This won't work, I get an error : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$nompage' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\show.php on line 91`

Comment: And please close your `while()` loop with an `}`

Comment: @RichardBernards Yes I have these and `$nompage` is set as;`$nompage = htmlspecialchars($_GET["nom"]);
$nompage = mysql_real_escape_string($nompage);`

Comment: @InxDev change you sql query `"SELECT * FROM ".$nompage." ORDER BY id"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should be -

```
'SELECT * FROM '.$nompage.' ORDER BY id' // if $nompage contains the table name
```

And avoid using `mysql`. It is deprecated. Try to use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be annoying for you, but you should use PDO instead of MySQL. MySQL syntax is deprecated. 
Anyhow, you may try this:

```
<?php
    //Pretty sure you need to give it either ASC or DESC.
    $v1 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM "'.$nonpage.'" ORDER BY id DESC');
    if($v1 === FALSE) {
        die('Erreur lors de la selection de la table.'); // TODO: meilleur erreur
    }
        while($liste = mysql_fetch_array($v1)){
    ?>
<tr>
    <th><?php if(isset($liste['nom'])){
    echo $liste["nom"];} ?></th>
    <th><a href="<?php echo $liste['lien1']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
    <?php echo $liste['lien1']; ?></a></th>
    <th><?php echo $liste['autre']?></th>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query= 'SELECT * FROM "'.$nonpage.'" ORDER BY id ASC'
$v1 = mysql_query($query);
if($v1 === FALSE) {
    die('Erreur lors de la selection de la table.'); 
}
while($liste = mysql_fetch_assoc($v1)){
?>

<tr>
<th><?php if(isset($liste['nom'])){
  echo $liste["nom"];} ?></th>
<th><a href="<?php echo $liste['lien1']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
<?php echo $liste['lien1']; ?></a></th>
<th><?php echo $liste['autre']?></th>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

use mysql_fetch_assoc insted of mysql_fetch_array